# Load balanced EC2 instances for high performance hosting?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

I have a fairly hefty Dell machine with dual quad-core cpus and 32GB memory.

On that machine I host a pretty busy forum, but the one machine does everything; web, cache, db, sphinx, etc. I also have a full-system, downtime-less backup done nightly.

This all costs me a smidge under $800 p/m (Australian prices are higher) and I don't really trust the backups.

As an experiment I set up the following;

- ELB with Auto scale rules (add new instance after 2 mins of 20%+ CPU, drop instance after 5 mins under 20%. Max 5 instances)
- Two EC2 instances (m3.large) across availability zones.
- One m3.medium for NFS (And will add cache and sphinx to this) - This just stores user uploads and it is served through Cloud Front.
- One db.r3.large RDS instance with my my.cnf copied to it as best I could (I'm not a db expert, my conf follows me everywhere)

In its current state its approx $600 p/m and worst case scenario (5 web instances) it comes in at roughly $1k.

It seems very, *very* good.

Last time I tried EC2 with my site it kept falling over at busy periods due to a lack of connection support on the single instances, so this time I kept the instances smaller and put the ELB in front. Apache Bench (-n 1000 -c 100) from my machine seems to go well with 8+ requests per second and 50% of requests under 11799ms (100% under 17763ms.)

What am I missing? This all seems too good to be true. I can have scheduled snapshots of my db done whenever I want, I can have as many machines as I want behind the ELB and in its current (2 instances) state I reckon it would be fine for 90% of the day.

Please provide feedback on this, I'm not a systems guy, I just love AWS stuff and my site seems perfect for AWS based hosting.

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to note here is that Network performance will scale up as the Instance size goes up.. I.E m3.xlarge will get you better NW Bandwidth compared to m3.large... I'm not sure an m3.medium will work for NFS (since you say you have a very busy site).. Please check the setup before you switch on the prod traffic. You could also leverage S3 + CDN to deliver static Contents. Also if you host an SSL site, consider SSL offloading in the ELB.

Comment: Hi @vijayrajah thanks for that info. The network speed has had me scratching my head. The NFS is mainly for writing as I serve static content from Cloud Front, I forgot to add that. It works on my existing host so no change. Will increase that if required.

Comment: FYI: In an m3.xlarge instance, we consistently get 80+ Mbit/s NW bandwidth when we do performance tests (us-east Region)..

Comment: What's the NFS server for? Hosting your application code or your user uploads? I'd deploy your code to every instance and modify your attachment functionality to use S3.

Comment: NFS just stores uploads and file cache. Actual app is deployed to each instance.

Comment: Instead of the EC2 for storing files investigate the use of S3. As there is no compute component it will end up cheaper and easier to maintain.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks. I've always found the mounting and direct use of S3 more difficult. I also need compute for search and memcache which will also run on the NFS instance.